# Change cell colour of column data depending on stock availability in Google Sheets

Tags: formula, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a way to alter cell colour depending on orders vs stock availability. Essentially, in the example given, I need the first two cells containing "1" to be highlighted, but not the "0" cell or the third "1" cell. The data is far larger for my sheet and also contains multiple columns (different items), but hopefully this example will suffice, then I can use the formula/conditional formatting for each column.

| Order | Stock = 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | This cell highlighted, as 2 are available. |
| 0 | This cell ignored as no order present. |
| 1 | This cell highlighted, as 2 are available. |
| 1 | This cell NOT highlighted, as 3 are not available. |

This is beyond me, as I could barely even think up the terminology to describe what I'm trying to do! Any help would be greatly appreciated.